# mongodb range sharding with string field

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I use 'id' field in mongodb documents which is the HASH of '_id' (ObjectId field generated by mongo). I want to use RANGE sharding with 'id' field. The question is the following:

How can I set ranges for each shard when 'shardKey' is some long String (for example 64 chars)?

Comment: This question is off-topic for StackOverflow as it is not about programming but a database administration issue and should be posted to [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com) instead. Setting shard keys is not about programming, but database design instead.

Comment: I need to add key in NodeJS and I think its programming.

Comment: Well I already cast a close vote so I cannot recast as completely unclear in what you are asking or asking to solve a problem with code when no code is provided. Those are both other valid close reasons that apply, so I would suggest you elaborate on your problem with edits if you would prefer an answer to a closed question.

Comment: @Olologin Of course you can as long as it is possible to set a "range" from the values contained ( which is basically the point of sharding in the first place ), but as stated that is a DBA issue and off-topic. ObjectId's are monotonic ( ever increasing, and also not a "string" ) and therefore "rangeable". But also a very poor choice for sharding unless you specifically want time based, which is the prefix to all ObjectId values anyway.

Comment: So you want to manually define which range of your hash key goes to which shard? Why would you want to do that? Hash ranges don't make any logical sense—hashes are random, so you won't have any real control over what data goes where. When you use hash-based sharding, it normally means that you want MongoDB to balance your data for you.

Comment: Yes. I want to use range-based sharding for performance and also get randomly divided data. I know that hash-based sharding solves the problem, but at the expense of performance.

Comment: @AraratHarutyunyan Sorry, but you cannot get both logical range sharding and randomly distributed data. It's either one or the other. If your ranges are also random, then why are you implementing the hash shard key yourself? Just use `sh.shardCollection("yourDB.yourCollection", { _id: "hashed" })`. MongoDB will handle random data distribution for you.

Comment: @DmytroShevchenko thanks, your comment was very helpful.

Comment: @AraratHarutyunyan you are welcome. I elaborate on the comment in my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want your data to be distributed based on a hash key, MongoDB has a built-in way of doing that:

```js
sh.shardCollection("yourDB.yourCollection", { _id: "hashed" })
```

This way, data will be distributed between your shards randomly, as well as uniformly (or very close to it) .

Please note that you can't have both logical key ranges and random data distribution. It's either one or the other, they are mutually exclusive. So:

- If you want random data distribution, use `{ fieldName: "hashed" }` as your shard key definition.
- If you want to manually control how data is distributed and accessed, use a normal shard key and define [shard tags](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/administer-shard-tags/).